# Thread on AlertDialog

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog

I created class that inheritance from AlertDialog. This class start thread that check some value over the internet (long operation time). The dialog have single button (POSITIVE_BUTTON). this button should be disable until the thread will end. But I don't know how to make this button enabled from the thread.

My code:

```
public MyDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    setView(view);

    getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Long operation time code
            getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true); // CRASH!!!
        }
    }).start();    
}
```

The error says that I change view from another thread. And I can't use the `runOnUIThread` method because it not exits in AlertDialog.
What should I do?

Comment: Could you pass an Activity in your constructor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to pass an `Activity` in your constructor, just do :

```
public class MyDialog extends AlertDialog {

    public MyDialog(Activity act) {
        super(act);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_launch, null);
        setView(view);

        getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);

        act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Long operation time
                getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true); // CRASH!!!
            }
        });  
    }

}
```

Comment: Won't that block the UI Thread by running the long operation on it? Seems to me like *only* the `getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true)` should be run on the UI thread...

Comment: @mbrenon Right. But the best plan will to implement an `AsyncTask` to perfom the _Long operation time_ here.

Answer (score 0):

You can not manage UI elements from a thread different from the UI thread

```
 public MyDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    setView(view);

    getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Long operation time code
           view.post(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                 View button = getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                  if (button != null)
                     button.setEnabled(true); // CRASH!!!
              }
           }
        }
    }).start();    
}
```

also you want to check for null values returned by the `getButton()`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the context you pass IS the calling activity, then:

```
public MyDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    setView(view);

    getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);

    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Long operation time
            getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true); // CRASH!!!
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: Wrong way, its not helps. The function `setEnabled` still called from the thread.